# How to connect to db via vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ole

I have the following code, the msgBox that says "DB changed" never shows up, and I get messages like follows in the immediate window.

But finally, the form loads, and I can't know whether my DB was created or not!

[image]

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)        
    conn.Open()
    Try

        conn.ChangeDatabase("productsDB")
        MsgBox("DB changed")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Try
            Dim command1 As New SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE productsDB", conn)
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery()

            command1.Connection.ChangeDatabase("productsDB")

            Dim command2 As New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE products ([id][int],[name][char](30),[quantity][int],[dealer_price][int],[unit_price][int])", conn)
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex2 As Exception
            MsgBox(ex2.Message)
        End Try
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: I'd recommend executing `MsgBox(ex.Message)` immediately in your outer Catch to see what the initial problem was.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful if you instantiate the connection, as well as open it, inside the try block to see the exception you are throwing.

```
Dim conn as SqlConnection
Try
  conn = new SqlConnection(strConn)
  con.Open()
  ...
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```